Ratios con filtro PowerBi
Estoy intentando crear una tabla con unos ratios de una columna pero que me filtre por otra a la hora de crearlos. Al hacerlo en ambas me suma 100% pese a estar filtrado.
Mis dos columnas son RMM.115 que es string y la otra Importe que es numerico
RMM tiene dos valores Alto/Bajo y el importe es la suma de los dos:
Lo que quiero es que para cada categoría me haga el % de Altos sobre el total y el de Bajos sobre el total Lo he intentado así:
RatioFiltrado = 
VAR FiltradoAmountDC = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(MyTable[Amount DC]),
        FILTER(
            MyTable, 
            MyTable[RMM.115.02.02] = "medium" || MyTable[RMM.115.02.02] = "low"
        )
    )
VAR TotalAmountDC = 
    SUM(MyTable[Amount DC])
RETURN
    DIVIDE(FiltradoAmountDC, TotalAmountDC, 0)

